# phpMyAdmin won't stop throwing "#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server "

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, privileges

I'm trying to enter `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` but I keep getting :

```
Error
MySQL said: 

#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I've tried to do what's written [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/lost-root-access-in-mysql-486785/) , [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) , [and also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878458/1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server) , [and last but not least - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885410/how-can-i-run-with-rootlocalhost-privileges-in-mysql) , however nothing works .

How can I fix this annoying message ?

Best regards

**EDIT:**

From `run` I hit `cmd` and `C:\Users\internet>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" "--def
aults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" "-uroot" "--host=127.0.
0.1"  "-p"`

Then I'm in :

```
C:\Users\internet>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" "--def
aults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" "-uroot" "--host=127.0.
0.1"  "-p"
Enter password: *******
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 23
Server version: 5.5.25 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

And then :

```
mysql> GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root'@'127.0.0.1' identified by '$roots_password' WI
TH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But still nothing  .

Comment: @sarnold: Added to my post . 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` like so:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by '$roots_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Since the host that is lacking is `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1`.