# Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server - grant to root@localhost not working

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I know this is a frequent topic , but...

I have installed a local mysql server on Windows 7 x64 via EzyPHP, but can't log in, except under the `--skip-grant-tables` option.

Login attempts generate the error: 
Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

So I've tried restarting with the --skip-grant-tables option.  This lets me log in as root, and even change the root password. So no problem with the password.  But not to run a grant statement.  This is what happens:

`GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'ROOT PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

returns:

`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement.`

I've also followed the instructions in other answers, such as here: [phpMyAdmin won't stop throwing "#1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513888/phpmyadmin-wont-stop-throwing-1130-host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-conne)

All I want to do is run a local mysql server to develop a php/mysql app, but this problem seems insurmountable.  Hopefully there is something simple I have missed, which you will be able to point out.

thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Not had any experience with windows, but firstly I would advise you create a user account for the application and limit that account to the database you're working with.

Secondly you need to tell the server to reload the grant tables, should the root account not have privileges allready.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dbpass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This keeps your root account free for administration. The 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' command will force the server to reload the grant tables, which means you can then connect as the new user.

Most UNIX/Linux type systems have a mysql_secure_installation command that streamlines this process, however like I said I've no experience with windows.

Comment: Thanks James.  That is all very good db practice.  My application doesn't use the root at all.  The problem I am wrestling with right now, in setting up this local development environment, is being able to log in to the database at all - regardless of the particular user or privileges.  Once that is sorted, the rest, can follow.

Comment: No problem, in which case login with --skip-grant-tables and run:

GRANT ALL ON __*.*__ TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: If only..  that's the problem.  In ---skip-grant-tables mode, all grant statements I've tried return "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement"