# Can't Acces Mysql / Phpmyadmin with error "(HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have problem from my phpmyadmin . i dont know what happen but after i restart my pc , i cant acces phpmyadmin . my Phpmyadmin didnt have password . i start my XAMPP normaly and this Apache and Mysql is running . but if i acces :

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

and Having error :

> (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

I acces using cmd and accessed :

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
```

but have same error

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

cant someone give me solution ? i try to search thread for solution but this solution is this error can acces Mysql , but i Cant . can someone helping me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IP instead:

```
DROP USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'%';
```

For more possibilities, [see this link](http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/36/en/i-get-error-1130-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-or-access-denied-or-could-not-connect-.html).

To create the root user, seeing as MySQL is local & all, execute the following from the command line (Start > Run > "cmd" without quotes):

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'mynewpassword'
```

or create a new user

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Where i can write this line on DROP USER 'roor'@'127.0.0.1' ? I cant acces mysql

Comment: instead of http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ try using the ip address to  connect 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin , and put this code in my.ini  config file and try  `skip-grant-tables`

Answer (score 5):

Go to `xampp\mysql\bin` (in your `xampp` folder, where your `htdocs` folder is), open the `my.ini` file and write at the end

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Then restart MySQL in the XAMPP Control Panel

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other MySQL server installed on the computer, export all the data into separate dump files and store those files somewhere safe (i.e. cloud storage).

After that, remove or uninstall the sever completely.

It should work.