# Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got the below error message when login in PhpMyAdmin even from the terminal:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed
>   to connect to this MariaDB server

This solution does not work :

```
[mysql]
skip-grant-tables
```

I use Xampp on windows10

Comment: I also had the same issue. Try this solution, maybe it helps. https://forum.laragon.org/post/5833

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Acces Mysql / Phpmyadmin with error "(HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999708/cant-acces-mysql-phpmyadmin-with-error-hy000-1130-host-localhost-is-not)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using xampp, then simply add
skip-grant-tables
below of [mysqld] and above of port= 3306 in C:\xampp71\mysql\bin\my.ini file.

Note: am using xampp with php7.1 and mariadb 10.3.16

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the user you are trying to use when authenticating with MySQL doesn't have permission.

You can fix this by making sure the user has the widest permissions:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Let me ask, even I can't login as root then where should I execute this query?

Comment: if you installed mariadb the setup should have asked you for the root password. 
In my case, running sudo mysql is enough to act as root for mariadb.