# Cannot connect to MySQL database from XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, database-connection, visual-paradigm

I'm finding this problem when trying to connect to a MySQL database running on a MySQL server from the XAMPP control panel. The server seems to be running correctly and all works fine until I want to open phpMyAdmin pushing the "Admin" botton of the control panel. I get the following error message on the browser.

[image]

This was the log of the latest start of the session server, where I doesn't find anything anomalous.

```
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2212605
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 2212614; transaction id 2984
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-06-20 15:52:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Despite that, the first time it occurred in the same day morning the error log showed:

```
2023-06-20 09:37:32 0x2b382023-06-20 09:37:32 0x86bc  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file D:\winx64-packages\build\src\storage\innobase\os\os0file.cc line 6154
InnoDB: Failing assertion: slot
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-06-20 09:37:32 0x8a7c  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file D:\winx64-packages\build\src\storage\innobase\os\os0file.cc line 6154
InnoDB: Failing assertion: slot
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

I find this error also in Visual Paradigm testing the database connection status, an error message I also get in the console every time I do database interaction operations, like create users in an web application I'm developing in Java using Eclipse:

```
Cannot connect to database
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.orm.ertodb.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:27)
    at v.aam.c.a(:66)
    at v.aam.c.b(:78)
    at v.aam.av.run(:25)
```

In addition, I'm not understanding why is it trying to connect to a MariaDB server if I selected InnoDB as engine.

No changes were made to the database or the server configuration from the last time the connection could be established. The IP address i use for the connection is 127.0.0.1 and port 3306.

Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL Workbench?  Its superior in every way to phpmyadmin and even supports all the main OS and is free.   --> D/L here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Acces Mysql / Phpmyadmin with error "(HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999708/cant-acces-mysql-phpmyadmin-with-error-hy000-1130-host-localhost-is-not)